Mathematical Induction, coin problem
Show that any amount in cent greater than or equal to 6 can be obtained using 2 cents and $b$ cents coins. Prove with the help of strong mathematical induction. Note: First find the correct value of $b$ cents, then you have to  solve it using mathematical induction.
Let $P(n) = n$ cents can be formed using 2 and 5 cent, hence $b=5$.
Basis: $P(6) = 2222$
$P(7) = 2(1)+5(1)\;25$
$P(8) = 2(4)\; 2222$
$P(9) = 2(2) + 5(1) 225$
$P(10)=  2(5)    22222$
$P(n) \implies n= 2s+5t  s \geq 0,  t=1, 0 \forall n \geq 10$
$s=\text{number of 2 cent coins}, t=\text{number of 5 cent coins}$.
There are two cases

odd sum (one 5 cent coin)
even sum (no 5 cent coin)
rest of answer

posting this question again, last time I was told my answer was not clear. I also need to know if and why writing this is important
valid $s+3 >= 0$, $s-2>= 0$

You are more likely to get help if you format your question carefully. As for the question itself, what is to prevent us from choosing $b = 1$? Then trivially every amount is attainable with 2 cent and 1 cent coins.

In the spirit of induction, you could have stopped at P(7) and P(8).  Do you see why?

i chose 1 initially, but then i discussed with bing, he said the solution will be too easy if i choose 1. If i choose 1, i will not even need 2 then :)

Cf. this question

So you require a solution that is difficult? I'm confused. Also who is Bing?

no, i will go with 1. If i do not go with 1, and go with 5 in stead,  is my solution correct?
another question, why would i need strong mathematical induction if i choose one, why won't simple induction work?

anyway, i will go with 1 now, thank you. my bad, i just thought they will not ask a simple question :).  bing=chatgpt=copilot, who is not that good at maths, but still i like to talk to him.
